# Show List and Submit form on same view in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a class Name Comment as follow

```
public class Comment
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Coment { get; set; }
    }
```

what I'm trying to do , i want to show list of comments and a form to add comment on same view(Index), this is what I have done, so far but I'm unable to get `hint`, this is my index view

```
@model IEnumerable<GuestbookEntryApp.Models.Comment>
<h2>Index</h2>
<div id="CommentList">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Comments</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var obj in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@obj.Name</td>
                <td>@obj.Coment</td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>
</div>
<br />
<div id="commentBox">
 @Html.Partial("~/Views/Comments/_AddComment.cshtml", new ViewDataDictionary { Model = new GuestbookEntryApp.Models.Comment() })
</div>
```

but here i'm unable to get hint `@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name)`
This is my controller

```
   public class CommentsController : Controller
{
    GuestbookContext db = new GuestbookContext(); // my DbContxt Class
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IList<Comment> _comment = db.Comments.ToList();
        return View(_comment);
    }
    public PartialViewResult AddComment()
    {
        return PartialView("_AddComment");
    }
    public PartialViewResult AddComment(Comment _comment)
    {
        db.Comments.Add(_comment);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

Is there any other way to do this.
I want like this
[image]

Comment: Where do people pick up bad naming conventions and habbits in .NET?

Comment: I was referring to the fact you're naming parameters with underscores, and named your property `Coment` because your class name is `Comment` rather than calling it Text or Body. 

Ditch your Add Comment action, it does nothing because your rendering partial, not rendering action.

Answer (score 2):

Create a view model with properties for the existing comments and the new comment

```
public class CommentVM
{
  public IEnumerable<Comment> ExistingComments { get; set; }
  public Comment NewComment { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@model YourAssembly.CommentVM
....
@foreach (var obj in Model.ExistingComments)
{
  ...
}

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddComment", .....}))
{
  @Html.LabelFor(x => x.NewComment.Name)
  ....
```

and adjust the controller to add the `Bind.Prefix` property

```
public ActionResult AddComment([Bind(Prefix="NewComment")]Comment _comment)
{
  ....
```